# Chrome Dev tools: Why sometimes a dominating CSS rule is crossed-out?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Normally a crossed rule means it is overridden by other rules somewhere, but in dev tool every now and then I see a dominating CSS rule being crossed-out, making me confused. See above picture. Please noted that changing the color in the crossed line actually affects the element on the page. Why is this?

Comment: I think you should also show which CSS rule is dominating this crossed rule. It might be a media query.

Comment: could it be because of the `!important`? Maybe there is a dominating style so its crossed out, but because of the !important it will take dominance

Comment: Media queries, inline styles, another !important.

Comment: *why sometimes* people ask questions without giving the particular example where they see inconsistent behaviour and expect to get an answer? Could you post the code reproducing the issue?

Comment: If it is not an error, it is not the most dominant selector.

Comment: This may not be a very good example, but I believe the 3 people who upvotes have had this problem before as I did. I will update this topic when I find more convincing examples.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, a style will be shown as struck-through if it exists in an matching rule but is commented out, or if you've manually disabled it by unchecking it within the Chrome developer tools. It will also show as crossed out, but with an error icon, if the style has a syntax error.